# Where to change Magento default tabs on products?

Tags: magento, tabs, product

I am struggling with a problem that I hope you can be helpful with.

I need to change the default product tabs on my product page, but I can't change it in the backend, only set the different attributes.

I have narrowed it down to a catalog.xml file, but I don't know where the exact code is controlling the tabs.

I tried to alter the code a bit, but with no effect. My Magento installation is also very slow, which is driving me mad...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to override core files in local module rather than changing the core file directly.
Here is an example how to override **Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs.php** 

Create a module For example **MyNameSpace_ModuleName** inside **app/code/local/**

To register a module create **app/etc/modules/MyNameSpace_ModuleName.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
   <MyNameSpace_ModuleName>
     <codePool>local</codePool>
     <active>true</active>
   </MyNameSpace_ModuleName>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**MyNameSpace/ModuleName/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyNameSpace_ModuleName>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MyNameSpace_ModuleName>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                <cataolg_product_edit_tabs>MyNameSpace_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tabs</cataolg_product_edit_tabs>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

---

**MyNameSpace/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/catalog/product/edit/tabs.php**

```
class MyNameSpace_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs
{
    protected $_attributeTabBlock = 'adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_attributes';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('product_info_tabs');
        $this->setDestElementId('product_edit_form');
        $this->setTitle(Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Product Information'));
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $product = $this->getProduct();

        if (!($setId = $product->getAttributeSetId())) {
            $setId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('set', null);
        }

        if ($setId) {
            $groupCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_group_collection')
                ->setAttributeSetFilter($setId)
                ->setSortOrder()
                ->load();

            foreach ($groupCollection as $group) {
                $attributes = $product->getAttributes($group->getId(), true);
                // do not add groups without attributes

                foreach ($attributes as $key => $attribute) {
                    if( !$attribute->getIsVisible() ) {
                        unset($attributes[$key]);
                    }
                }

                if (count($attributes)==0) {
                    continue;
                }

                $this->addTab('group_'.$group->getId(), array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__($group->getAttributeGroupName()),
                    'content'   => $this->_translateHtml($this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->getAttributeTabBlock(),
                        'adminhtml.catalog.product.edit.tab.attributes')->setGroup($group)
                            ->setGroupAttributes($attributes)
                            ->toHtml()),
                ));
            }

            if (Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_CatalogInventory')) {
                $this->addTab('inventory', array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Inventory'),
                    'content'   => $this->_translateHtml($this->getLayout()
                        ->createBlock('adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_inventory')->toHtml()),
                ));
            }

            /**
             * Don't display website tab for single mode
             */
            if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
                $this->addTab('websites', array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Websites'),
                    'content'   => $this->_translateHtml($this->getLayout()
                        ->createBlock('adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_websites')->toHtml()),
                ));
            }

            $this->addTab('categories', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Categories'),
                'url'       => $this->getUrl('*/*/categories', array('_current' => true)),
                'class'     => 'ajax',
            ));

            $this->addTab('related', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Related Products'),
                'url'       => $this->getUrl('*/*/related', array('_current' => true)),
                'class'     => 'ajax',
            ));

            $this->addTab('upsell', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Up-sells'),
                'url'       => $this->getUrl('*/*/upsell', array('_current' => true)),
                'class'     => 'ajax',
            ));

            $this->addTab('crosssell', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Cross-sells'),
                'url'       => $this->getUrl('*/*/crosssell', array('_current' => true)),
                'class'     => 'ajax',
            ));

            $storeId = 0;
            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('store')) {
                $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore($this->getRequest()->getParam('store'))->getId();
            }

            $alertPriceAllow = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/productalert/allow_price');
            $alertStockAllow = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/productalert/allow_stock');

            if (($alertPriceAllow || $alertStockAllow) && !$product->isGrouped()) {
                $this->addTab('productalert', array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Product Alerts'),
                    'content'   => $this->_translateHtml($this->getLayout()
                        ->createBlock('adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_alerts', 'admin.alerts.products')->toHtml())
                ));
            }

            if( $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', false) ) {
                if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_Review')) {
                    if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('admin/catalog/reviews_ratings')){
                        $this->addTab('reviews', array(
                            'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Product Reviews'),
                            'url'   => $this->getUrl('*/*/reviews', array('_current' => true)),
                            'class' => 'ajax',
                        ));
                    }
                }
                if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_Tag')) {
                    if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('admin/catalog/tag')){
                        $this->addTab('tags', array(
                         'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Product Tags'),
                         'url'   => $this->getUrl('*/*/tagGrid', array('_current' => true)),
                         'class' => 'ajax',
                        ));

                        $this->addTab('customers_tags', array(
                            'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Customers Tagged Product'),
                            'url'   => $this->getUrl('*/*/tagCustomerGrid', array('_current' => true)),
                            'class' => 'ajax',
                        ));
                    }
                }

            }

            /**
             * Do not change this tab id
             * @see Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs_Configurable
             * @see Mage_Bundle_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs
             */
            if (!$product->isGrouped()) {
                $this->addTab('customer_options', array(
                    'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Custom Options'),
                    'url'   => $this->getUrl('*/*/options', array('_current' => true)),
                    'class' => 'ajax',
                ));
            }

        }
        else {
            $this->addTab('set', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Settings'),
                'content'   => $this->_translateHtml($this->getLayout()
                    ->createBlock('adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_settings')->toHtml()),
                'active'    => true
            ));
        }
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

You can add new Tabs inside _preparelayout() function. In same manner you can also override other files and can change whatever you want to change. 
 For proper reflection of changes, make sure you have clean the cache.

Comment: I have now set up the folders, but how do I activate that module?

Comment: @RenéHansen: To register you module you just need to create a xml file MyNameSpace_ModuleName.xml inside app/etc/modules/ folder. For your understanding i am updating the code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think that I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can find tab in this block file app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tabs.php

If you are looking into this tab you can find particular action of tab

For example related product it has this kind of url `$this->getUrl('*/*/related', array('_current' => true)),` this url in turn call this adminhtml_catalog_product_related action and this action is specify in catalog.xml.

```
 <adminhtml_catalog_product_related>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
        <block type="adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_related" name="catalog.product.edit.tab.related"/>
        <block type="adminhtml/widget_grid_serializer" name="related_grid_serializer">
            <reference name="related_grid_serializer">
                <action method="initSerializerBlock">
                    <grid_block_name>catalog.product.edit.tab.related</grid_block_name>
                    <data_callback>getSelectedRelatedProducts</data_callback>
                    <hidden_input_name>links[related]</hidden_input_name>
                    <reload_param_name>products_related</reload_param_name>
                </action>
                <action method="addColumnInputName">
                    <input_name>position</input_name>
                </action>
            </reference>
        </block>
    </block>
</adminhtml_catalog_product_related>
```

so you can find easily what you want to change.

Comment: Thanks, I found the file and I will check it out.