# How to change Related product title block in Magento

Tags: magento, block, title, product

Want to know, how can i change the block title of Related product block in magento? I mean that, i want to replace the title named "Related product" with my own text.

Thanks

Mostaq

Comment: Do you want to change the `block` name or title in admin panel?

Comment: Please Define Where TO you want to change Your Content: i have fronted and back-end option define see bellow.

Comment: On the frontend, you probably can use the translate table, lots of stuff like this doesn't need to have template files hacked just to change wording.

Answer (score 2):

Hello check below file

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list/related.phtml or
app/design/frontend/your_current_theme/default/template/catalog/product/list/related.phtml

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
After GO to Your related page and see the red line with book
 icon to click on it and replace your text without Going To file System.
```

[image]

[image]

```
For Backend Related Product Tab Label Change for 

1) direct change on core file:
  app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tabs.php
  find Related and replace

2)Create Module to dynamic :
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481564/where-to-change-magento-default-tabs-on-products
```